# Likes on posts on a heavy trafic site

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this website that lets people post stuff that other people can like, on all the main pages it shows a certain amounts of small tumbs with the amount of likes the post has. The website also has a 'hot' page wich shows the most liked post in the last 24 hours.

i curently was thinking  about making the database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `liked` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

but iam scared it will cause a lott of performace isues sinds the table will get really big really fast so to query it all it will slow my database down alott, would there be a good way to index this to help with performance? also would it be a good idea to make a second table just for the 'hot' page containing only the likes of the last 24hours wich i then take out the expired (older then 24hours) with a cron job every day?

im far from a expert on databases so some explination with the awnser would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: What happens to the like after 24 hours?

Comment: if you index the table correctly linking `post` with the PK of your post table and join it with your main post query then memcache it your good to go.

Comment: Heavy loaded table should never be `myisam`

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: I vote for composite `post+liked` key

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone have you got a example or can you explain it a bit more? like i said im not much of a expert on how to do this so it would really be appreciated if you could explain a little bit more

Answer (score 1):

Your method would work if it is important to you to log who made which "likes". The table will grow linearly with use, which should not be a performance problem unless the site becomes very popular. Just be sure to use InnoDB tables as MyISAM will lock the entire table on writes and that is a write-heave database.

If simply knowing the amount of likes is sufficient, then do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And on each "Like" run this query:

```
UPDATE posts SET `likes` = `likes`+1 WHERE id = {$id}";
```

Comment: 1. This won't work in case if the post haven't been liked yet. 2. This won't be able to calculate the most liked post in 24 hours 3. +1 for mentioning innodb and myisam locking issues

Comment: MyISAM doesn't lock table on INSERT in most cases: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html

Comment: i need to know who made the like as becaus on there profile it will show what they have liked and i need a time so i can calculate.

Comment: If you need to know who made the like than the table than the method that you mention in the OP is the best method.

Comment: @zerkms: Thank you for mentioning that it will not work if posts have not been liked yet. I assume that a row for each post will be made with likes=0 when the post is made. Thanks!

Comment: @dotancohen: or you can suggest using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: @zerkms: While that will work, I do not like to use that in instances where the likely case is that the key already exists. Though, to be honest, I have never benchmarked it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can do one thing, First add the "Like" in your ***likes*** table and create another table naming "hotlikes" or whatever you want to call it....

Keep a field in *hotlikes* for DATE, and add date into it, automatically delete the dates which of previous date by creating a *cron job*

Show only 24hrs like from "hotlikes" table....

Comment: yea this is what i had in mind aswell but it still doesnt solve my fear for the size of the likes table and the performance

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have fairly large MySql(lets say aws ec2 large instance) which has been tuned properly, indexed properly, uses innodb as storage engine and uses caching you wouldn't have problem serving 100-200 simultaneous users. You will also have to consider what other tables or databases are on the same database machine is doing.

I suppose the post and user in the schema refers to the ids if yes then I would create the following indexes

1. Primary key (obviously)
2. post + timestamp
3. user + timestamp (I am guess you might want to query by users if not then this is not required)

Every 24 hours I will run script to build the top likes and store it in some kind of cache so that it can be retrieved with out hitting the db server wit optional write to db (fail safe just in case cache failed).

Another option is to use key-value stores(redis maybe) but them again it depends on whats yours use case and how much users you will have.

Comment: thank you this is really usefull, im gonna do some research on what you suggested and decide what would work best after that

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @Abhilash Shukla suggested you to, plus you can cache the number of likes on the post in the `post` table. You can update the cache once per X minutes, for example, like VBulletin and some other forums do for thread views. For this, you can create a table to store just id's of the posts, for which you need to recalculate the amount of likes. And do recalculation on cron.

You can even [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) likes table by postid range, if you find that suitable for the task.